# Configuration DefaultValue Behaviours

Tags: c#

```
[ConfigurationProperty("Name", DefaultValue = "test")]
public string Name
{
    get { return (string)this["Name"];  }
    set { this["Name"] = "Ram"; }
}

CorticonConfig config = new CorticonConfig();
string test = config.Name;
```

I have a property with "Name" and also I am setting the value to name.While I m trying to get the value, I am getting default value.

My question is: can we set property value as above?

And what is the behaviour of `Default` value property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506323/canonical-example-of-configurationproperty

Comment: Class Config
{
 [ConfigurationProperty("Name", DefaultValue = "test")]
 public string Name
 {
    get { return (string)this["Name"];  }
    set { this["Name"] = "Ram"; }
 }
}

Class setValue
{
 public void setvalue()
 {
 CorticonConfig config = new CorticonConfig();
 config.Name = "test";
 }
}

Class Present
{
 public void getvalue()
 {
  CorticonConfig config = new CorticonConfig();
  string test = config.Name;
 }
}

Comment: Here I am getting the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Your property setter doesn't work like you think it's working.

The `set` part is executed when you set the property (you make `property = something`), and in that case, your `something` would be on the `value` keyword.

So in your case, if you do:

```
CorticonConfig config = new CorticonConfig();
config.Name = "whatever";
string test = config.Name;
```

`test` will have `"Ram"`, because you are always asigning that value there, but it won't execute that code unless you do `config.Name = <something>`.

The correct way to have a setter like that would be:

```
   set
   {
     this["Name"] = value;
   }
```

And if you need a default value other than the one you are setting on your attribute, apply it after constructing the object:

```
CorticonConfig config = new CorticonConfig();
config.Name = "Ram";
```

The `DefaultValue` you pass on the attribute gives it a default value if no settings have been ever saved, so when you read it, it'll return that.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. However, Why I am getting the default value??

Comment: I have edited my answer since I misread your initial question

Comment: Hi, I have set the value for Name property(Config.cs) in some other cs(SetValue.cs) file and then retriving in present.cs but I am getting default valu.

Comment: I don't understand. If you are doing something specific which is causing an issue, add it to your question

Comment: Class Config
{
 [ConfigurationProperty("Name", DefaultValue = "test")]
 public string Name
 {
    get { return (string)this["Name"];  }
    set { this["Name"] = value; }
 }
}

Class setValue
{
 public void setvalue()
 {
 CorticonConfig config = new CorticonConfig();
 config.Name = "Ram";
 }
}

Class Present
{
 public void getvalue()
 {
  CorticonConfig config = new CorticonConfig();
  string test = config.Name;
 }
}

Comment: You should edit your question, not paste all your code in a comment with no formatting. And also, make sure you give all the needed data so we don't have to figure out everything. I really suggest you to read [this link](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints) . We don't even know what `CorticonConfig` is (we are just wild-guessing), let alone the rest of your classes.